# sandbox-exec: deny network access but allow socket

Tags: macos, darwin

I am using MacOSX's `sandbox-exec` to deny network access for a command (like e.g. described in [this article](https://www.davd.io/os-x-run-any-command-in-a-sandbox/)).

Unfortunately this also seems to deny MySQL access to it's socket:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

The profile-file for sandbox-exec is this:

```
(version 1)
(allow default)
(deny network*)
```

Is there a way to restrict only TCP/internet network access but leave socket access unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

Found out. The profile file has to contain `(allow network-outbound (to unix-socket))`:

```
(version 1)
(allow default)
(deny network*)
(allow network-outbound (to unix-socket))
```